# Не удается спрятать объект jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Задача вроде бы тривиальная, но в чем проблема не могу понять. Вот кусок кода js:

```
var photosessions = $(".photosession_");
if (photosessions.length > 2) {

    for (var i = 2; i < photosessions.length; i++)
        photosessions[i].hide();
}
```

Вот генерируемый html 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возникает ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самое интересное, что если написать так, все дивы пропадают.

```
photosessions.hide();
```

Что с этим делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`photosessions[i]` возвращает DOM-элемент, а не обертку jQuery.

```
$(photosessions[i]).hide();
```

или

```
photosessions.eq(i).hide();
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень признателен